# Sequelize group records in a table by month

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to count all records and groups by every month. I saw many posts that used "date_trunc" but "date_trunc" not working for me. how to overcome this? please, check the expected output.

this is my **code:**

```
let saleByAllMonth = await Order.findAll({
  attributes: [
    [db.sequelize.fn("DATE", db.sequelize.col("date")), "date"],
    [db.sequelize.fn("count", "*"), "count"],
  ],
  group: ["date"],
});
```

**output:**

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "saleByAllMonth": [
        {
            "date": "2023-01-07",
            "count": 2
        },
        {
            "date": "2023-01-08",
            "count": 7
        },
        {
            "date": "2023-01-09",
            "count": 14
        },
        {
            "date": "2023-01-11",
            "count": 12
        },
        {
            "date": "2023-01-13",
            "count": 2
        },
        {
            "date": "2023-01-14",
            "count": 2
        },
        {
            "date": "2023-01-19",
            "count": 3
        },
        {
            "date": "2023-01-30",
            "count": 2
        },
        {
            "date": "2023-02-13",
            "count": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

But I want this type of **expected output:**

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "saleByAllMonth": [
        {
            "date": "1",  or "2023-01-01"
            "count": 49
        },
        {
            "date": "2", or "2023-02-01"
            "count": 3
        },
     ]
}
```

Comment: which DB you are using?  data_trunc is available in certain DBs but not available for ie MySQL.

Comment: Using mariadb / MySQL. @Emma

Comment: I see.  If the data is only for a year you can use `MONTH` function, otherwise, `EXTRACT` is perhaps the closest function to `date_trunc`.   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: thank you so much! @Emma, It's work on "MONTH" change code 

``` attributes: [
        [db.sequelize.fn("MONTH", db.sequelize.col("date")), "month"],
        [db.sequelize.fn("count", "*"), "count"],
      ],
      group: ["month"] ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thank you so much, @Emma. Change “DATE” to "MONTH" and its works.

**Previous code:**

```
let saleByAllMonth = await Order.findAll({
  attributes: [
    [db.sequelize.fn("DATE", db.sequelize.col("date")), "date"],
    [db.sequelize.fn("count", "*"), "count"],
  ],
  group: ["date"],
});
```

**Update code:**

```
let saleByAllMonth = await Order.findAll({
  attributes: [
    [db.sequelize.fn("MONTH", db.sequelize.col("date")), "month"],
    [db.sequelize.fn("count", "*"), "count"],
  ],
  group: ["month"],
});
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "saleByAllMonth": [
        {
            "date": "1",
            "count": 42
        },
        {
            "date": "2"
            "count": 3
        },
     ]
}
```